# How to convert a distance in meters to pixels?

Tags: flutter, dart, openstreetmap, pixel, distance

I'm building a **Flutter** app and I want to draw circles on a map using the `flutter_map` package. The circles that I want to draw have a radius on meters, I want to convert the distance in meters into a distance on pixels, how can I do so ?